# Get user logged on sharepoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript

I need to create notifications for every user who didn't read a specific new on the site. To do this i need to see who user is logged in the site and then save this info into a list on Sharepoint. The problem is that i don't know where can i get this info on Sharepoint Online.
I whould like to do this using javascript.

Someone can help me whith this. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Best and simple way to get current logged in user name is _spPageContextInfo.

**_spPageContextInfo**:

`_spPageContextInfo` is a global variable usually available on any SharePoint page. This variable stores basic information about current web and current user.

Below are the Some examples:

1. **To Get User Display Name**:

   ```
   var currentUserName = _spPageContextInfo.userDisplayName;
   ```
2. **To Get User Login Name**:

   ```
   var currentUserLoginName = _spPageContextInfo.userLoginName;
   ```
3. **To Get User Id**:

   ```
   var userID = _spPageContextInfo.userId
   ```
4. **To Get User Email**:

   ```
   var userEmail = _spPageContextInfo.userEmail
   ```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use Rest API getting current user data:

```
 var url = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/currentuser";  
    $.ajax({  
        url: url,  
        headers: {  
            Accept: "application/json;odata=verbose"  
        },  
        async: false,  
        success: function (data) {  
            var items = data.d; // Data will have user object      
            console.log(items);
        },  
        eror: function (data) {  
            alert("An error occurred. Please try again.");  
        }  
    });
```

This is the response data checked in Browser Console:
[image]