# Any way to get user logged report in sharepoint office 365

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365

Is there any way to get user logged details report in sharepoint online office 365.Any suggestion would be helpful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want to get the details of current user logged in or something else?

Answer (score 1):

In SharePoint online, you can get the current logged in user by using this code.

```
var userID=_spPageContextInfo.userId;
```

Answer (score 0):

Best and simple way to get current logged in user name is _spPageContextInfo.

**_spPageContextInfo**:

`_spPageContextInfo` is a global variable usually available on any SharePoint page. This variable stores basic information about current web and current user.

Below are the Some examples:

1. **To Get User Display Name**:

   `var currentUserName=_spPageContextInfo.userDisplayName;`
2. **To Get User Login Name**:

   `var currentUserLoginName=_spPageContextInfo.userLoginName;`
3. **To Get User Id**:

   `var userID=_spPageContextInfo.userId;`

**Reference**:

1. [Get user logged on sharepoint online](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/252579/get-user-logged-on-sharepoint-online/252599)

Comment: Have you tried this? Does this answers your question?