# How to get current user login name in Modern script editor webpart?

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-pages

I'm getting the error Object doesn't support property or method 'ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded'.

Below is my code.

```
    SP.SOD.ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(getCurrentUser, "sp.js");

function getCurrentUser() {
    var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var web = context.get_web();
    currentUser = web.get_currentUser();
    context.load(currentUser);
    context.executeQueryAsync(onSuccess, onFail);
}

function onSuccess(sender, args) {
    var acountname = currentUser.get_loginName(); // extract the login name from the account name
    alert(acountname);
}

function onFail(sender, args) {
    alert('Failed to get current user' + args.get_message());
}
```

Comment: Can you please paste the full working code? even after enabling _spPageContextInfo, I am still getting error in the modern page. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to enable _spPageContextInfo option in Modern Script Editor Web Part:
[image]

Then test again to see if it works:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Perfect! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Best and simple way to get current logged in user name is _spPageContextInfo.

**_spPageContextInfo**:

`_spPageContextInfo` is a global variable usually available on any SharePoint page. This variable stores basic information about current web and current user.

Below are the Some examples:

1. **To Get User Display Name**:

   `var currentUserName=_spPageContextInfo.userDisplayName;`
2. **To Get User Login Name**:

   `var currentUserLoginName=_spPageContextInfo.userLoginName;`
3. **To Get User Id**:

   `var userID=_spPageContextInfo.userId`

**Reference**: [Get user logged on sharepoint online](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/252579/get-user-logged-on-sharepoint-online/252599)

Comment: Ganesh, I have already tried this but it didn't work.

Comment: Where are you trying to use this code?